# Add Data to a Document In Cloud Function: How To Stop Circular Callback?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

### Problem

Is there a way I can update a field on a document's `onUpdate` listener and ensure the listener isn't called again?

### Details

I have a `revenueItem` that's associated with a `company` and want to copy the company's name onto the `revenueItem` to ensure data integrity.

On create/update, I get the `companyId` off the `revenueItem`, get the company document, and set `revenueItem.companyName` to the `company`'s name--pretty basic stuff to ensure every `revenueItem` has a `companyName` on it; I don't trust clients ;-).

The problem is the `onUpdate` listener is called *again* because I've updated the `revenueItem`, and all the logic in the listener fires (I'm doing more than just updating the company name in the listener, btw).

### Ideas (I don't like)

#### Store the company name on a subcollection of the `revenueItem`

That'll make my client code more complex because I'll have to fetch the `revenueItem` and it's associated sub-collection

#### Store some flag that says "updated on server"

I don't like storing state information as data on a document, seems messy, plus I can imagine this process being pretty buggy.

### Notes

I'm coming from a Java RDBMS background and expect to be able to do these kinds of things. Am I just stuck in my ways and need to embrace the new New that I should trust my client code more? I keep imagining some hacker crafting JSON that doesn't properly set the de-normalized `companyName` field and cause *the end of the world as we know it*.

Comment: make a flag, and check it on the same function, I normally add a updated_at timestamp, and check on the onUpdate if the code doc change in the last 1, 5, 10 minutes... also a bool can work on your case, actually, this is very common

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @andresmijares, a `lastUpdated` field with a date is understandable, but since I have no guarantee when functions are called, it would only be a guess how long the time gap would be that I would exit the function, and it could introduce problems if my aggregating code didn't run. The updated flag isn't ideal, I think.

Comment: I agree, also you can create a small map to hold the information for this function and set a boolean which marks it as processed or not, next time it runs the value should updated